# Detach a filter driver from certain drivers?

Tags: windows, drivers

The driver for my laptop's keyboard has a kernel-mode filter driver from Synaptics (SynTP.sys) attached. Is it possible to detach the SynTP.sys filter driver from my keyboard's driver, without detaching it from my Touchpad's driver?
[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816071) Microsoft Support page explains how to completely disable a filter driver, but my touchpad requires SynTP.sys as well.

I'm trying to do this is because the Synaptics driver disables my touchpad when I type. (Explained fully in this question: [Use touchpad while "typing"?](https://superuser.com/questions/504571/use-touchpad-while-typing).) Since I don't have a solution to that problem, I figured removing the filter driver from the keyboard could prevent the Synaptics driver from detecting key strokes, thus stopping it from disabling the touchpad.