# My Sony Vaio Touchpad freezes

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, sony-vaio

My Sony VAIO laptop's (SVE14A2M1EB) touchpad freezes once in a while (say every 2-3 minutes, but it's very variable). It suddenly stops responding completely for 0.5-10 seconds and then spontaneously works absolutely fine. When it freezes, no feedback anywhere on the touchpad makes it work again, ie. there isn't a dead spot somewhere in the touchpad.

I have Synaptics Clickpad V8.1 for modifying mouse properties (ie. SmartSense, sensitivity etc.), and one of the options shows me the cursor location/input location (see the last picture in this thread posted by japzone - the map on the left shows, when activated, the location of the curser [Use touchpad while "typing"?](https://superuser.com/questions/504571/use-touchpad-while-typing/515925#515925)), and here's the thing: While the mouse is completely frozen, the "cursor location"-map actually shows, that the mouse is working, ie. it follows the touchpad input. That makes me think, that it's not a hardware problem, but more of a software problem.

Other than that, the multifinger gestures and the tapping doesn't work sometimes. Both when the touchpad is frozen and isn't. That isn't a problem for me, but it might be helpful trying to diagnose the actual reason for the problem.

I've tried to:

- Install drivers (and other things) from the laptop's support
  http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/SVE14A2M1EB/updates
- Try toinstall drivers directly from Windows by letting Windows search for
  the drivers itself
- I've also tried to change the settings in Synaptic
  Clickpad by increasing/decreasing the different values like
  sensitivity
- I've also tried to change the settings in Synaptic
  Clickpad by increasing/decreasing the different values like
  sensitivity
- Reinstall Windows 8
- Turn the laptop off, remove
  battery+charger, keep pressing the on/off button for a while, and
  then plug everything back and turn it on.

EDIT:
I've plugged an external mouse and it works fine. It doesn't solve the touchpad problem though.

Comment: What about the Windows 7? did you have same problem in win7?

Comment: I don't know since the laptop comes with Windows 8. Do you think that the OS might be the problem?

Comment: hard to follow you, but if you attach an external mouse will it work while your touch pad freezes? Can you maneuver with keyboard shortcuts while your touch is frozen? I would remove all traces of the touch pad utilities and drivers, and start from scratch and add software slowly until it acts up.

Comment: @Ali, such a nice name, I love that :) , you know, Windows 8 has many problem with some hardware, so if it possible,change your windows or check it via compatible mode...

Comment: @Logman: I've edited the post: External mouse via USB works, but doesn't solve the touchpad problem.

Comment: @Sam, thanks! :-) How do I check it via compatible mode?

Answer (score 1):

When frozen try a 3 finger tap. Use 3 fingers and double tap. Bam! It should start working again.