# how can I use touchpad while holding a letter or number in the keyboar?

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse, delay, hp

I am using an HP laptop. When I hold a number or letter key from the keyboard and I use my mouse, the mouse just freezes and does mot respond. I think the touchpad is Synaptics TouchPad

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "Hit windows key+R, type "regedit" inside of it expand these folders: HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > PrecisionTouchPad
After clicking on the "PrecisionTouchPad" folder search for "AAPThreshold" on the right part of the window and double click it or right click it and click modify. Change the value from whatever it is (probably 2 or 3) to 0 and click OK. Restart you computer and it should work.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/644428/how-to-enable-synaptics-touchpad-while-typing-without-disabling-palmcheck

Comment: Please check if the post in the above link solves the problem. If it does, then your question is a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable Synaptics Touchpad While Typing (without disabling palmcheck)?](https://superuser.com/questions/644428/how-to-enable-synaptics-touchpad-while-typing-without-disabling-palmcheck)