# No option to disable "smartsense" in synaptics touchpad driver

Tags: windows, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I am unsure what to do a this point, I've tried multiple versions of synaptics and there is no option to remove smartsense for me.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: What makes you think there should be an option to remove it?  Your question as it's currently written is extremely broad.  You should edit the question and reduce the scope of the question.

Comment: Because there usually is, smartsense stops your touchpad when you type which is incredibly annoying.

Comment: The option doesn't exist if you are using Windows 10

Comment: Have you been over the the answer(s) here: http://superuser.com/questions/504571/use-touchpad-while-typing ?  If so, what exactly did you try, and what were the results?

Comment: Two questions, one, is that a screenshot of your computer? Two, if so, have you tried looking into what the gear icon does. I am sure you have tried it, but incase not...

Comment: @SenorContento - It doesn't matter where the screenshot is from.  The option, isn't suppose to be there, when its installed on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1:

> In the Registry, go to the key
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Defaults`, and set the
> value of all string entries of the form `PalmKms…`, to `0`.  These
> values determine the amount of ms that the touchpad stays disabled
> after keyboard input has been detected.

Step 2:

> 1. Type WIN+R and start "regedit"
> 2. Confirm that you're an admin (a window may pop up).
> 3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Install`
> 4. Change `DeleteUserSettingsOnUpgrade` from 1 to 0
> 5. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPCpl`
> 6. Change `RestoreAllDefaultsfrom` 1 to 0
> 7. Now you can change the ClickPad-Settings (of course, they will not be deleted after a restart, and you can change them as many times as
>    you want to)

Source: [How to disable "Smartsense" on Synaptics Touchpad?](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/How-to-disable-quot-Smartsense-quot-on-Synaptics-Touchpad/td-p/5415573)

After you perform Step 1 and Step 2 you also want to navigate to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\TouchPadPS2_2TM3139` and set `PalmRT` to 0.

After you completed all the above steps, you will have to restart your machine, in order for the changes to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Registry Editor, either by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `regedit` in the Run dialog and hit enter, or simply typing "regedit" in Windows Start.

1. In the Registry go to the following key:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Defaults
   ```

   and set the value of ***all*** string entries of the form `PalmKms…` to `0`. These values determine the amount of ms that the touchpad stays disabled after keyboard input has been detected.
2. Then go to the key:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Install
   ```

   and change `DeleteUserSettingsOnUpgrade` from `1` to `0`
3. Then to

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPCpl
   ```

   and change `RestoreAllDefaultsfrom` form `1` to `0`

   Now you can change the ClickPad-Settings as many times as you want, which will not be deleted after a restart.
4. You may also need to go to:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\TouchPadPS2_2TM3139
   ```

   and set `PalmRT` to `0`.

After you completed all the above steps, you will have to restart your machine in order for the changes to take affect.

[Convenient .reg file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/laggingreflex/0b1b9c0804f9d436f4a436053eb10286/raw/2b68b9490634b191a26c3b16aeb1931264d82374/Synaptics.reg) to do all above.

Source: [How to disable "Smartsense" on Synaptics Touchpad?](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/How-to-disable-quot-Smartsense-quot-on-Synaptics-Touchpad/td-p/5415573)

Answer (score -1):

first go to regedit and set all these values to zero.

regedit->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->SYNAPTICS->SYNTP->DEFAULTS PalmKms, should be 24 in total.

It's easy, right click each one and select modify then change the value to zero.

then go settings, devices, mouse and touchpad and set touchpad to no delay

then go to additional mouse options under touchpad and click on your clickpad settings and click on the cog next to smartsense

finally move the tapping and pointing time to the left, and MOST IMPORTANTLY move the top bar FAR RIGHT not left so it's at MAX. This will solve the annoying problem once and for all. Spread the word. It,'s bar to MAX NOT min.

hiphappy1

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.