# Impossible to disable touchpad/trackpad in Windows 10 which regularly causes bluescreens (SynTP.sys, HKKbdFltr.sys)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse, touchpad

It seems to be a well known problem that bluesceens with message

> DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

are caused by touchpad drivers `SynTP.sys` und `HKKbdFltr.sys`. As I do not need the touchpad anyways (I use a mouse) I want to disable it, but it seems to be impossible.

It happens while working or gaming if I accidently touch the touchpad for whatever reasons.

*Here is what I have tried to get rid of this:*

**a) Update the touchpad drivers to the newest version**

Did not help anything - the touchpad keeps causing bluescreen at least if a mouse is connected.

**b) Disabling the touchpad in the Windows touchpad settings**

Obviously impossible - look at the screenshot:

[image: Touchpad disable not available in Windows 10]

**c) Disabling the touchpad via the device manager**

[image: Disabling touchpad via device manager]

Most devices can be *deactivated* or *uninstalled* on my notebook, but not the touchpad. You can *only uninstall* it.

I uninstalled:

- Synaptics WBDI Fingerprint Reader
- Insyde Airplane Mode HDI Mini-Driver
- Synaptics SMBus Touchpad

As I think those drivers are touchpad related. I restarted my notebook and Windows automatically installs those again.

It seems like it is impossible to get rid of my problem causing touchpad that I do not need. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many posts to be found of people having the same problem
and many solutions, some of which I have listed below.

I can see that you have the option to uninstall the device.
The problem is that it will reinstall itself on the next reboot.
An idea for preventing the reinstallation of the device might be to follow the instructions on
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672)
to block Windows Update from updating the Synaptics device.

Another option you should disable (if you have it) is in
PC Settings, under Devices, Touchpad.
Disable the touchpad and
clear the "Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected" option.

It might also help to go to Control Panel, Hardware and Sound,
Devices and Printers, Mouse.
On the "Device Settings" tab, clear the option
"Disable internal pointing device when external USB pointing device is attached" (again, if you have it).

On some Dell laptops, the setting to disable the touchpad is located in the Dell's support software : Open the Touchpad application in Dell Pointing Devices,
select the mouse and check the option for
"Disable Touchpad when USB Mouse present option".

A regedit [answer](https://superuser.com/a/515925/8672) advises to
go to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Defaults`,
and set the value of all string entries of the form `PalmKms…`, to 0.
These values determine the amount of ms that the touchpad stays disabled after keyboard input has been detected.

Another [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1304015/8672) also advises
in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPCpl` to set the value of
`RestoreAllDefaults` to 0, and in 
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Install`
the value of `Delete User Settings` to 0, and restart the computer.

Still another [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1308564/8672) advises
downloading and installing an older driver from
[here](https://www.sagernotebook.com/drivers/mouse/p640re/win10/05_TouchPad.exe).
This apparently destroys the touchpad in some unclear manner.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I think there are like two-three possibiliities I did not try yet. I will accept if anything works and let you know (Notebook is a custom gaming notebook from XMG therefore manufacturer specific solutions probably are not known).